# CSS in JS, how to make props.className the priority class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui, react-hooks

We need components where the class passed as props should have more priority than the default class.

> When passing classes as a prop, the component gives priority to the
>   class created in his own file.

**Text.jsx**

```
// this will be a component in another folder, it will be used in the whole app so it 
// should haveDYNAMIC styling
function Text(props) {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    default: {
      fontSize: 18,
      color: "black"
    }
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classNames(classes.default, props.className)}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**App.jsx**

```
function App() {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    title: {
      fontSize: 80,
      color: "red"
    },
    notGoodPractice: {
      fontSize: "80px !important"
    }
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Text className={classes.title}>Text in here is 18px</Text>
      <Text className={classes.notGoodPractice}>
        Text in here is 80px
      </Text>
    </div>
  );
}
```

React Snippet => [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-yalow-39vdz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: CSS doesn't have a concept of a "priority class". Certain CSS selectors do have higher precedence and selectivity - but the rules aren't simple: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/precedence.html

Comment: this would be easy in the **normal precedence**, i would just write the default class at the start of the .css file, and write all the other classes under it :, the real problem is in CSS IN JS

Comment: this is quit hard to do it this way, in css it doesn't master who comes last in classname attribute, what maters is what come last when you define the css rules. It's not similar to the spreed operator or Object.assign. If what you want is making the component decoupled from style, then later inject the style to look as you want, I refer this post: https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/decoupled-styling-ui-components/?gh_src=4n3gxh1

Comment: Did you try with string literal like this `className={`${classes.default} ${props.className}`}`. I can not test this right now. But as fas as remember I had the same issue and used it like this.

Comment: @octobus tried .... didn't work. Fun fact: className library does the exact same thing

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj Yeah I assumed that too. I am curious about the solution, I hope you can find and answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can prioritise classes passed as props this way.

Just make sure you don't apply `makeStyles` on it so that you can access them correctly in child.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

// this is how we will use the Text component
function App() {
  const style = {
    title: {
      fontSize: "80px",
      color: "red",
      "@media (max-width: 767px)": {
         color: "green"
      }
    },
    notGoodPractice: {
      fontSize: "80px"
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Text class1={style.title}>Title should be with size 80px</Text>
      <Text class1={style.notGoodPractice}>Title should be with size 80px</Text>
    </div>
  );
}

// this will be a component in another folder, it will be used throw the in app so it should be as DYNAMIC as possible
function Text(props) {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    default1: {
      fontSize: 18,
      color: "black"
    },
    priorityClass: props => props.class1
  }));

  const { default1, priorityClass } = useStyles(props);
  return <div className={`${default1} ${priorityClass}`}>{props.children}</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Check out live sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-voice-mb60t

Comment: I clearly have that in the demo, 
.notGoodPractice: {
      fontSize: "80px !important"
 }
Think it as a library, should everyone add !important to style a component ?!

Comment: That's what we have already implemented, but it seems that it doesn't scale so good.
Let's say I need to add shadow too (just in 1 case), we will need to get back to that component **every day**.
+ THERE is no way how you will do the **media query** with this solution.

Comment: You can pass a separate class in that scenario to that one component only

Comment: Anyway, that's what you would do if you were doing it the normal way

Comment: of course, that would work, but passing few styles as a prop and few as a class make no sense to the next maintainer of the project (if it would be a personal project that would be the solution I would have gone).
thanks for your time

Comment: You can pass raw objects and use them as per your needs in child. This way you also maintain consistency

Comment: Don't pass them to makeStyles and it would be scalable solution

Comment: You are being really helpful, but still :p what if I want the text to go in fontSize=40   when in mobile **media query**, it would either need to do a wrapper with the width of the device and form the logic of media query yourself ... (these calculations are costly for our app + it would reinvent the wheel).
That's why the whole question was made on how to prioritize the classes because css is built-in for media queries.

Comment: I can't see a problem go unsolved;). Please check the updated answer with media queries